# Why shape median point doesn't cut the shape symmetrically?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shapes

I'm designign some really simple draft for sketching a pitch offer for a customer. I'm not a designer, I opened Photoshop (for me it is a lot faster than AI, at least for very basic things the likes I usually do) and drew a shape (fat arrow) picking from the list. The box is a rectangle 17cm high, the arrow looks to be centered just fine. However I noticed that the shape median point doesnt match with the arrow tip. How is it possible?

[image]

This is the result, I dragged a guide just to better show the disparity between the median point of the shape and the actual arrow tip. I didn't stretch the arrow, just dragged into the box. Of course the correct 50% of the rectangle is the one in the guide. However I cannot figure out why it is not matching the shape.

Comment: Because the arrow isnt symmetrical?

Comment: @joojaa I picked a shape from the list and didn't stretch it, I don't understand. Why they put something like this as preset?

Comment: @S.W.G. - you could just draw your own arrow. Use the grid and snap grid, to make sure it's symmetrical. [see example](https://imgur.com/iOagNWZ)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whoever made that list of presets or clipart, must either have

- tried to create some kind of optically corrected shape
- or they simply had to generate alot of basic shapes to quickly fill some library with common looking things